# Xquery: Counting the number of occurrences of a term in each record within a set of records

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Given a set of xml records and a set of terms `$terms` . The terms in `$terms` sequence are extracted from the set of records. I want to count the number of occurrences of each term in each paragraph record. I used the following code to do so:

```
for $record in /rec:Record
for $term in $terms
return   xdmp:unquote(concat('<info>',string(count(lower-case($record/rec:paragraph )[. = lower-case($term)])), '</info>'))
```

For each term in each record i got 0 count:

[image: result]

Example: `$term:='Mathematics'`, `$record/rec:paragraph:='Mathematics is the study of topics such as quantity'`

I want the number of occurances of the term Mathematics in `$record/rec:paragraph`

Any idea of what caused this result? Is there any other way to count the number of occurrences of each of the terms in each paragraph.

Comment: There are several apparent problems with your query, but without an example of the XML you are querying, it's not possible to say for sure.

Comment: Are you looking for a count of `rec:paragraph` who's computed string value is equal to the lower-cased `$term` values, or that `contains()` (hint, hint) those values? Also, you might want to lower-case() the string value of the `rec:paragraph`. Example inputs and desired result would be helpful.

Comment: I have added an example. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tokenize() to split up the input string into word tokens. Then the counting itself is trivial. For example:

```
let $text := 'Mathematics is the study of topics such as quantity'
let $myterms := 'mathematics'
let $wds := tokenize($text, '\s+')

for $t in $myterms
return <term name="{$t}">{count($wds[lower-case(.)=lower-case($t)])}</term>
```

Returns this:

```
<term nm="mathematics">1</term>
```